# retreiving data from Room as LiveData does not trigger observer in some cases only

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, observers

In my app i use the Room library to handle user data, all the functionality has been implemented like in the "Android Basics in Kotlin" Tutorial Unit 5 on developer.android.com.
In one fragment i need to fetch a single item out of the database - for that i implemented the function in the fragment's viewmodel:

```
fun retrievePlaceItem(id: Int): LiveData<PlaceItem> {
    return itemDao.getPlaceItem(id).asLiveData()
}
```

the ItemDao is passed into the ViewModel Factory from the Room Database instance, which itself is instantiated in the custom Application class.
this is the query used in the ItemDao interface:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM placeItem WHERE id = :id")
fun getPlaceItem(id: Int): Flow<PlaceItem>
```

Data in the ItemDao is returned as a Flow, and turned into LiveData in the fetching function.
The Fragment itself observes the return of the function with a passed id, and when the observer triggers, the value is stored in a lateinit var of the corresponding datatype.

```
lateinit var placeItem: PlaceItem

...

override fun onViewCreated(...) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    ...
    val id = navigationArgs.itemId
    sharedViewModel.retrievePlaceItem(id)
        .observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner) { selectedItem ->
            placeItem = selectedItem
        }
    ...
}
```

this works flawlessly, the item is retrieved, the observer  gets triggered, and the lateinit var placeItem is initialized for further use.

in another fragment, that follows later on, i use a different viewmodel with the exact same function - i try to retrieve the value in the exact same way, observing the function return within the onViewCreated method of the fragment. the code is exactly the same, and i tried comparing it to the things taught in the tutorial - no deviations whatsoever. when i now go to use the value, i get an error

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property placeItem has not been initialized

after inspecting my code using logs, i understood the following:

- the viewmodel function to retrieve the item is called
- the correct item id is used
- the code inside the observer curly brackets is *not* executed

i tried using the same viewmodel in both fragments, anything until there was no more conceivable difference between these two pieces of code. yet the first one works, the second one doesn't. something in my code creates a difference between the two instances of me using the database to fetch an item.

Comment: It is incorrect to use `lateinit` on a property that is not initialized in `onViewCreated(), because you aren't guaranteeing that it is initialized at the earliest opportunity. A LiveData is updated some time in the future. That opens up your property to being left in an uninitialized state. Typically, you should not need to copy the value to some local property anyway. It suggests a design error somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thank you for the input, i've rewritten my code to avoid the local lateinit property entirely, and things are working just as expected. seems like the roadblock in front of me was that large that i didn't even notice the obvious solution at first.

Answer (score 1):

I avoided the problem by moving the other functions, that will handle the lateinit var, into the observer brackets. i'm unsure as to why that was not needed in my other fragment, but this works just fine!